# Cannot override a type with non-volatile upper bound

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds, volatility, non-volatile

I have a compiler error in scala and I don't know what does it refer to:
Assume these declarations:

```
trait Abstract {
  type MyType
}
trait AInner
trait A extends Abstract{
  type MyType <: AInner
}
trait BInner {
  def bMethod : Int
}
trait B extends Abstract with A{
  override type MyType <: BInner with A#MyType
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here(in trait `B`) is to further restrict the type `MyType` declared in `Abstract`, so any value of type `MyType` must extend all the `MyType`s in the mixin tree.

The compiler is giving me this message(as in title):
*type MyType is a volatile type; cannot override a type with non-volatile upper bound*. I understand, that **type volatility** is happening here because of type conjuction `with A#MyType`, the part of the error: **type with non-volatile upper bound** probably refers to the type declaration `type MyType <: AInner`, where `AInner` is not an abstract type thus non-volatile.

Why can't I do it? Is there a way, how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Removing this check in the compiler lets us shine a light on the potential for unsoundness.

```
diff --git a/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala b/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala
index 37a7e3c..78a8959 100644
--- a/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala
+++ b/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala
@@ -5128,8 +5128,7 @@ trait Typers extends Adaptations with Tags {

       def typedSelectFromTypeTree(tree: SelectFromTypeTree) = {
         val qual1 = typedType(tree.qualifier, mode)
-        if (qual1.tpe.isVolatile) TypeSelectionFromVolatileTypeError(tree, qual1)
-        else typedSelect(tree, qual1, tree.name)
+        typedSelect(tree, qual1, tree.name)
       }

       def typedTypeBoundsTree(tree: TypeBoundsTree) = {
```

Then, running the code from a compiler test case for illegal type selection for volatile types:

```
scala> class A; class B extends A
defined class A
defined class B

scala> trait C {
     |   type U
     |   trait D { type T >: B <: A }
     |   val y: (D with U)#T = new B
     | }
defined trait C

scala> class D extends C {
     |   trait E
     |   trait F { type T = E }
     |   type U = F
     |   def frob(arg : E) : E = arg
     |   frob(y)
     | }
defined class D

scala> new D
java.lang.ClassCastException: B cannot be cast to D$E
```

As I understand it, the issue stems from the fact that Scala doesn't have true intersection types.

```
scala> type A = { type T = Int }
defined type alias A

scala> type B = { type T = String }
defined type alias B

scala> "": (A with B)#T
res16: String = ""

scala> 0: (A with B)#T
<console>:37: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: String
              0: (A with B)#T
              ^
```

This might change in the future, if the research into [Dependent Object Types (DOT)](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~amin/dot/fool.pdf) bears fruit.

Comment: Why are also abstract method members forbidden in non-volatile types?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite `trait B` with (more later about your goal, which, I think, is a bit different)

```
trait B extends A {
  type MyType <: BInner with AInner
}
```

And this makes total sense. A value of type `B#MyType` can be seen as either a `BInner` or a `AInner`.

You don't need to repeat `Abstract` because `A` is already a subclass of `Abstract`. You don't have to write `override` as this is implicit for a type declaration. So the question is why `A#MyType` is not working as `AInner`?

Here is what the scala language spec says about volatile types.

> 3.6 Volatile Types
>
> Type volatility approximates the possibility that a type parameter or abstract type instance of a type does not have any
>   non-null values. As explained in (§3.1), a value member of a volatile
>   type cannot appear in a path. A type is volatile if it falls into one
>   of four categories: A compound type T1 with ... with Tn {R } is
>   volatile if one of the following two conditions hold.
>   1. One of T2, ..., Tn is a type parameter or abstract type, or
>   2. T1 is an abstract type and and either the reﬁnement R or a type Tj for j > 1 contributes an abstract member to the compound type, or
>   3. one of T1, ..., Tn is a singleton type. Here, a type S contributes an abstract member to a type T if S contains an abstract member that
>   is also a member of T . A reﬁnement R contributes an abstract member
>   to a type T if R contains an abstract declaration which is also a
>   member of T . A type designator is volatile if it is an alias of a
>   volatile type, or if it designates a type parameter or abstract type
>   that has a volatile type as its upper bound. A singleton type p.type
>   is volatile, if the underlying type of path p is volatile. An
>   existential type T forSome {Q } is volatile if T is volatile.

Other important item mentioned by the spec is about abstract type overriding:

> Another restriction applies to abstract type members: An abstract type member with a volatile type (§3.6) as its upper bound may not
>   override an abstract type member which does not have a volatile upper
>   bound.

The compiler error is:

```
error: overriding type MyType in trait A with bounds <: AInner;
type MyType is a volatile type; cannot override a type with non-volatile upper bound
```

This is consistent with the spec. `BInner with A#MyType` is volatile. Before that `MyType` had a non-volatile as `Any`.

The matter is that a type in the scala type system must have a unique meaning. An abstract type can be thought as a type which declaration is deferred to a subclass. Therefore there is no problem for declaring values of an abstract type when it is still abstract. On the other hand if we have a type like `BInner with A#MyType`, this type may have several meaning. It is called volatile and it does not makes sense to have a non null value of this type, as it could have as many types as subclasses instantiating the `MyType` abstract type. To simplify things, we could think of a volatile type as a type not being a subtype of `Any` (and volatile as being a subtype `Any`). We therefore have a contradiction that the compiler mentions.

Coming back to your goal, which you stated as

> What I'm trying to achieve here(in trait B) is to further restrict the type MyType declared > in Abstract, so any value of type MyType must extend all the MyTypes in the mixin tree.

You can achieve this thanks to inner traits like this.

```
trait Abstract {
  type MyType
}
trait B extends Abstract {
  trait MyType {
    def bMethod : Int
  }
}
trait A extends B {
  trait MyType extends super.MyType {
  }
}
```

Well I hope this somewhat what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation that "because `A#MyType` is abstract, `BInner with A#MyType` is bizarre" is correct. It's perfectly valid to write, for example, `AInner with Abstract#MyType` although it appears equally bizarre. The spec is quite clear about _where volatile types may be used_, but not as informative about _what they mean_ (that is, why the rules regarding them are necessary for soundness). The only hint there is that they "approximate the possibility that a type does not have any non-null values," and I don't think your argument captures that.

Comment: @mergeconflict I reworked the argument and hope it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this?

```
trait B extends Abstract with A {
  override type MyType <: BInner with AInner
}
```

In any realization of `trait B`, `MyType` will always be the same type as seen from `trait A`, so upper-bounding it by itself does not make any sense.

If in the upper piece of code, it bothers you that you'll have to rewrite `trait B` if you change the bound in `trait A`, use:

```
trait A extends Abstract{
  type ABound = AInner
  type MyType <: AInner
}
trait B extends Abstract with A {
  override type MyType <: BInner with ABound
}
```

Comment: That appears to be a good solution, but the thing I still don't understand is why it's necessary. My comment on Leo's answer is the same here... The spec is quite clear about _where volatile types may be used_, but not as informative about _what they mean_. The only hint there is that they "approximate the possibility that a type does not have any non-null values," but I'm guessing that's a misleading explanation in this context. Any thoughts?