# Does Dotty support refinements?

Tags: scala, structural-typing, dotty, scala-3

I am reading in dread what will come with Scala 3, paying particular attention to changes to compound types. They were always somewhat of a hack, so clean, true intersection types are certainly an improvement. I couldn't find though anything about what happens to the actual refinement part of the compound type. I rely heavily in my current project on strongly interwoven types in an attempt to have every returned value be as narrow as possible. So, for example, having

```
trait Thing { thisThing =>
    type A
    type B
    type C

    def something :Thing { 
        type A = <related to thisThing.A> 
        type B <: <related to thisThing.B>
        type C = <etc>
    }
```

Is it even still possible? How to achieve this goal with the new semantics? As I understand, refinements of abstract types will almost certainly be not allowed, so it will be difficult to have a 'self type' declaration in a root of a type hierarchy:

```
trait Thing {
    type ThisThing <: Thing
    type A
    type B
    def copy(...) :ThisThing { type A = ...; type B = ... }
}
```

On a somewhat related note, I was looking at structural types. I must say I like how we can dynamic member selection/implementation with static declarations. Is it though possible for abstract classes? Could I write something like:

```
trait Record(members :(String, Any)*) extends Selectable { ... }

val r = new Record { val name :String; val age :Int }
```

EDIT: I found the relative bit of documentation and it looks like anonymous `Selectable` instance are exempt from the rule that the type of an anonymous class is the intersection of its extended types - good.

Comment: Where did you get that this would not be possible?

Comment: IIRC you'll only need `Selectable` if you want a refinement type inferred, otherwise, it'll work pretty much the same as in Scala 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I understand, refinements of abstract types will almost certainly be not allowed...

```
type A <: {
  type U
}

trait B {
  type T <: A
}

object o extends B {
  type T = A { type U = Int }
}
```

perfectly compiles.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Nbz3GxoaTSe3VhXZz406vQ

What is not allowed is type projections of abstract types `T#U`

```
trait B {
  type T <: A
  type V = T#U // B.this.T is not a legal path since it is not a concrete type
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xPylqOOkTPK9CvWyDdLvsA

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/type-projection.html

Maybe you meant that

```
type A {
  type U
}
```

is not parseable. But in Scala 2 it isn't either. Correct is either

```
trait A {
  type U
}
```

or

```
type A <: {
  type U
}
```

Comment: Weird. I distinctly remember commenting on this yesterday, but evidently didn't post it for some reason. Thanks for clearing that up - it is possible I had that mixed up with volatility. I was aware that type projections are dropped (the main reason for that feelng of dread) and I must have extended it in my mind to refinements. Are volatile types still a thing, or did the DOT calculus tighten things  up enough for them to not be needed?

Comment: @Turin I guess volatile types is a Scala-2 thing. I guess they were a workaround to avoid issues caused by unsoundness of type projections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880438/cannot-override-a-type-with-non-volatile-upper-bound